# How to add event listeners in loop - Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: dom-events, titanium, addeventlistener, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am bringing data from a POST query my webservice to build a dynamic menu. What I want is that the system hear the click event of each view, and identify what it is. But I do not know what's going on because the `eventListener` is not added ...

My code below:

```
getCategorias.onload = function() {
            
    var json = this.responseText;
    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    
    
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var containerAll = Ti.UI.createView({
            width: "100%",
            height: 130,
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            id: response[i].id
        });
    
        
        
        var viewImage = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundImage: "http://www.iconomize.com.br/admin/"+response[i].foto, 
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            opacity: "0.5",
            width: "100%", 
            height: "100%",  
            top: "0"
        });
        
        var labelCat = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color: "#fff",
            textAlign: "center",
            width: "90%",
            text: response[i].nome
        });
        
        
        containerAll.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            alert(e.source.id);
        });

        
        containerAll.add(viewImage);
        containerAll.add(labelCat);
        

        $.listCategories.add(containerAll);
        
    }
    
    
    $.activityIndicator.hide();
};
```

Comment: I think better thing is that just add listener on `$.listCategories` once and in the listener function check with the `id` like `$.listCategories.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            alert(e.source.id);
        });`

Comment: Just a practical note: it's not a good idea to put listeners in a loop. Listeners are passive and don't really need to be allocated dynamically. I like @Suraj idea of adding them to a list, then calling them when needed. If you need to remove them, you can then loop through the list and apply `removeListener()` iteratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding eventListener in loop, you can add a eventListener on list.

```
$.listCategories.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
   alert(e.source.id);
   //Do the required thing by using container id
});
```

Also you can set

```
viewImage.touchEnabled = false;
labelCat.touchEnabled = false;
```

Just to make sure you will receive container view as e.source when click on image or label.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "touchEnabled:false" to the image and the label. Than it's working fine (Android, Ti SDK 5.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

Actually what has worked for me is to create a function like this outside of the for-loop:

```
function handler(_obj)
{
    _obj.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        alert(_obj.id);
    });
}
```

Then in your for-loop just add the following: `handler(containerAll);`